# Auto Commas In UITextfield With Decimal Pad Keyboard

Tags: swift, swift2, uitextfield

I am using a UITextField that has a Decimal Pad Keyboard. So the user can only type in numbers. I would like the textfield to auto add commas to every thousand the user types. So that the user can easily identify how much they are typing. Is there a common way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27309040/6623548) is the reference. below is the converted swift code. set the delegate to the textField and implement the delegate method below.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let cs = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "0123456789").invertedSet
    let filtered = string.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(cs)
    let component = filtered.joinWithSeparator("")
    let isNumeric = string == component

    // check for input string is numeric value or either a number not a string or character.
    if isNumeric {
        let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 10

        let newString = (textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
        let numberWithOutCommas = newString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(",", withString: "")
        let number = formatter.numberFromString(numberWithOutCommas)
        if number != nil {
            let formattedString = formatter.stringFromNumber(number!)
            print(number)
            print(formattedString)
            textField.text = formattedString
        } else {
            textField.text = nil
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308595/how-do-you-dynamically-format-a-number-to-have-commas-in-a-uitextfield-entry) answer should help. They have added commas in the shouldChangeCharactersInRange method. 
Here is the swift equivalent

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
let formattedNum = formatter.stringFromNumber(10000000)
textField.text = formattedNum
```

Comment: I am fairly new to iOS. I am not completely understanding. Why is there a number of 10,000,000? Also I tried entering 2nd line of code and Xcode is not picking it up.